# How to make padding reusable for Scaffold content

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

How can I set the `content` in my `Scaffold` to be reusable with content padding. Is it possible to extract `contentPadding` from a composable when I declare it? i.e. `MyScaffoldContent`

> Cannot find a parameter with this name: contentPadding

```
@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldTitle: String, scaffoldContent: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.exitUntilCollapsedScrollBehavior()

    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection),
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = scaffoldTitle) },
                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
            )
        },
        content = { contentPadding ->
            scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding)
        }
    )
}

// Example composable
@Composable
fun MyScaffoldContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Header $item",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}

// Example update
@Composable
fun MyHomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldTitle = "Hello Android",
        scaffoldContent = MyScreenContent(contentPadding = ?))
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScreenContent(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()) {
    Text(
        text = "Header",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want the `MyHomeScreen` composable to use the value of the content padding from `MyReusableScaffold`, you have to define a `parameter` in the `scaffoldContent` lambda and pass the `contentPadding` to it.

```
@Composable
fun MyReusableScaffold(scaffoldContent: @Composable ( contentPadding: PaddingValues) -> Unit) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {

        },
        content = { contentPadding ->
            scaffoldContent(contentPadding = contentPadding)
        }
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyScaffoldContent(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues()
) {
    Text(
        text = "Header",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}

@Composable
fun MyHomeScreen(navController: NavController) {
    MyReusableScaffold(
        scaffoldContent = {
            MyScreenContent(contentPadding = it)
        }
    )

//    or 
//    MyReusableScaffold(
//        scaffoldContent = {
//            MyScaffoldContent(contentPadding = it)
//        }
//    )
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to replicate the `contentPadding` code in [this video at 9:17](https://youtu.be/Og2p9LczE3A), so that instead of using a single composable, I want to use any composable of my choice. Please see my "Example update" code; `ERROR - Required: (PaddingValues) → Unit, Found: Unit`

Comment: Edited my answer, though I omitted some of it to keep it short, but those are still your actual codes.

Comment: Here is a [timestamped link](https://youtu.be/Og2p9LczE3A?t=557) for the video mentioned in the comment above by @wbk727